# Can I make pancakes with waffle mix?

Tags: pancakes

It's thanksgiving, bought pancake mix to enjoy on a cold morning with the family. It had bugs in it from the store.

I have waffle mix, but my iron is MIA. Can I make pancakes or something alike using the waffle batter I have on hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.The basic ingredients for both are the same; the difference lies in how they are cooked.

Comment: There is usually a little extra oil/fat in the waffle mix...gives a crispier exterior, which is a good thing.

Comment: they were just a bit more flaky and tough, but served the need.

Comment: This answer is a little too simple for my taste. Using the same recipe for pancakes and waffles will result in mediocre waffles. Good waffles are lighter and more fatty. The extra eggs (or beating the egg whites) gives waffles a less cakey texture. The extra fat makes them more crisp as Doug said. Sure- the biggest difference is the iron but saying that is the *only* difference is sad.

Comment: Actually, the there is a key difference in the Review as well. More sugar and pool for waffles to make them crispy. Pancakes are fluffier, more cake-like. Pancakes meet with waffle mix will be thinner and not so fluffy, because of the extra oil.

Answer (score 2):

They'll both cook up well either way; we often use pancake recipes for waffles (and just make sure to grease the iron well).

If you have the ingredients on hand, it's also not difficult to make pancakes from scratch -- eggs, flour, baking powder, butter, eggs, salt.   Search online, and you'll find lots of recipes.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you very well can! I have Krusteaz Waffle Mix and instead of the box directions I just mixed it with water and they came out great!