# Does it matter if I make waffles in a frying pan?

Tags: equipment, waffle

I have some waffle batter ready (here is [the recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/whole-wheat-waffles-recipe)) but I don't have a waffle iron. Is it okay if I make it the way I make pancakes, by pouring batter in a frying pan?

Comment: Did you end up trying them in the frying pan? How'd they come out?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like your question is actually whether you can make pancakes with waffle batter. You can certainly give it a try, especially since you already made the batter. Not sure exactly how the texture will turn out, but the ratios are pretty similar to pancake batter so they'll probably be good enough you'll be happy eating them.

They won't be waffles, though. Waffles are defined by their shape, which allows them to cook from both sides at once, getting all the surfaces nice and brown, with plenty of extra surface area from all the holes. If you don't have a waffle iron, you're not going to be able to make them.

Comment: This is a good answer, since it seems the OP is just going to make pancakes with waffle batter (and [that question has been asked before](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9449/15018)). I'd just add that the recipe listed is really a waffle recipe, with extra oil/butter compared to pancakes. Pancakes made with it will be richer and taste more "fried" than usual. This batter may also be a bit thinner.  It likely won't make thick, fluffy pancakes, but something between a pancake and a rich "fried crepe" in taste/texture.

Comment: @Athanasius Thanks, somehow I missed the oil when I was looking at the rough ratios. I guess with a waffle iron that'd help prevent sticking and make them even more nicely brown and crispy, but in a pan you wouldn't get the full benefit. Perhaps being sure to cook on the hot side would help.